# How to choose between NextJS 12 and 13

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am new to NextJS. I learned create-react-app and wrote some projects. Now, I want to learn NextJS. On Youtube, I watched several videos about both versions. However, I noticed that their architecture is quite different. While in 12 we have pages folder with strange naming _app.ts etc. On the other hand, in version 13 we have a layout.ts file. However, version 13 that have src/app folders architecture, but does not have a pages folder. I am thinking about learning version 13 instead of 12, but afraid of missing some knowledge from 12 that might not be covered in version 13. What is your advice for me guys?

Comment: Why not use the **latest** version available when starting a new project?

Comment: Definitely just use the latest version, you'll have longer support and be future-proofing your project.

Comment: Hi You can find answer at below link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76767919/pages-folder-not-working-in-next-js-13-as-in-previous-versions/77054460#77054460

Answer (score 2):

You are safe to use NextJS 13 and deploy it to production, but it is not recommended to use any experimental feature such as **app** for production

Answer (score 0):

Next 13 is stable release with awesome features and has turbo bundler which bundles assets faster than NextJS 12

Answer (score 0):

Just use the latest version. However /app is not yet production-ready so you can ignore that for your production build.

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers, unless you want to share new insights