# Pages folder not working in Next Js 13 as in previous versions

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm trying to learn NextJs 13 and I've been used to using the Pages folder and within them creating new folders or pages with routing without problems, but I see that in NextJs 13 it doesn't work the same way and it's time to create a folder for each page. I want to know how I can use the Pages folder as before or solutions.
I would also appreciate if anyone knows the directory structure that should be followed. Thank you.

I try to use the pages folder as in previous versions of Nextjs 13

Answer (score 1):

Pages directory is now optional.

If you find yourself comfortable using Pages Router instead of App Router, you can create a 'pages' directory at the root of your project.

You can create index.js (or index.tsx if you are using typescript) inside your pages folder.

Similarly, you have to create an _app.js (or _app.tsx) on your own in the Pages directory to define the global layout and _document.js (or _document.tsx) to control the initial response from the server.

Public folder is also optional.

Thanks